# Timing Belt Alignment Troubles

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Im Making a Cosworth BD Series Engine and im having an issue in aligning the Teeth on the timing Belt Without altering the rotation of the crank and camshafts or their Pullies.

The Belt Used has 146 Teeth on it and I just cant seem to get it to work the toothed pullies in question are 40, 40, 40, 22 and 20 (Cam, Cam, Distributor, Water Pump and Crank) with 2 Idler Pullies.

[image]

Can someone assist in my Mechanical endeavour[image]

Comment: Hi :) What exactly is it you are asking for help with? Is it rigging, animating the motors rotation/ alignment, something else? Please [clarify your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199206/edit) so that it does not depend on a file. (It helps to share what you have done so that others don't repeat your efforts also)  Thanks :)

Comment: alignment issue the belt doesnt want to line up with the pullies

Comment: Some problem found: 1) Teeth sizes are not the same between gears. 2) The curve of the belt is not truly offset from the gear. I would suggest building mechnical parts with CAD packages, like FreeCAD or Fusion360. Please note I have no engineering background.